# What does "it is finished" mean?

Tags: old-testament, crucifixion, sacrifice, covenants

In Old Testament sacrifice, High Priest said 'It is finished' when he had killed the lamb; to say it is finished lamb had to die and then the sacrifice was finished. But Jesus Christ said it is finished before His death even though death was necessary to complete a sacrifice.

Some say "the sin debt was paid in full" when He said "it is finished" as if death was not necessary or is it that "it is finished" phrase means something else in both covenants?

Comment: Could you quote the Old Testament verse where the High Priest says it is finished?

Comment: @Lawson This is an interesting question. But maybe not all denomiantions hold the same view on this. So please choose one denomination you want to hear of.

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site. As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Comment: I think this question would be better asked on biblical hermeneutics site. In fact a similar one has been asked an answered there that you may find helpful. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/27958/11555

Comment: @Kris The question in Bible Hermeneutics does not deal with the OP's interest in Old Testament sacrifices/covenants and the aspect of Christ's death.

Comment: @Lesley I did not say it did but I am saying this question that is not asking for a denominational perspective would fit better over there don’t you think?

Comment: @Kris Yes, I understand the OP hasn't specified any denominational perspective although reference has been made (in Marc's answer) to "Evangelical and Reformed traditions".

Comment: @Lawson Please specify which denominational perspectives you are interested in by selecting 'edit' then adding the appropriate tags. If you don't know how to do that you can leave a comment here and we can apply the denominational tags you want.

Comment: Please specify whose viewpoint you are interested in.  Once you do so, answers from that perspective can be undeleted and the question reopened.  Open-ended questions like this lead to discussion and debate, which we try to avoid as a Q&A site.